# Can we migrate report share to public group using unlocked package?

Tags: public-group, report-folder, folder-share

Can we migrate report share to public group using unlocked package?

We do have public group metadata in the unlocked package and the report folder metadata in the unlocked package which includes share of this folder for a public group.

However, this change is not reflected when unlocked package is installed in the target org.

Why? Is this completely impossible to achieve?

I have verified [metadata coverage report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/60) and both Group and Report Folder are covered. Public Group is available in non-namespaced packages (which unlocked packages mostly are by the definition)

[image]

while Report Folder is supported even regardless namespace settings

[image]

Why then

```
<folderShares>
    <accessLevel>Manage</accessLevel>
    <sharedTo>GroupName</sharedTo>
    <sharedToType>Group</sharedToType>
</folderShares>
```

folder share is not deployed upon package installation?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like we are forced to use Metadata API deployment instead of package installation